# Optimize query for for cumulative result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this query to find out item count for every month of year. But I am looking for a optimized query for cumulative result

```
SELECT 
 COUNT(ITM.ID) AS ItemCount,
 Month(ITM.ItemProcureDate),
 Year(ITM.ItemProcureDate)
    FROM 
    Rpt_Item ITM
    WHERE 
    ITM.ItemProcureDate IS NOT NULL       
    AND 
    ITM.ItemStatusID = 2         --       Item sold, Item Rejected 
    AND 
    ITM.ItemProcureDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME,'02/01/2014',1)   --@Beg_Date 
    AND 
    ITM.ItemProcureDate <= CONVERT(DATETIME,'04/12/2014',1)   --@End_Date 
    GROUP BY
    Month(ITM.ItemProcureDate),
    Year(ITM.ItemProcureDate)
```

Query result should be like this:

```
Item sold In month      2
Item Sold Till Month        2
Item Rejected           1       
Item Rejected Till Month    1
Year                2014
Month               Feb
Last Date of Month      02/28/2014

-----------------------------------------------
Item sold In month      2
Item Sold Till Month        4
Item Rejected           1       
Item Rejected Till Month            2
Year                2014
Month               March
LastDate of Month       03/31/2014

-----------------------------------------------
Item sold In month      2
Item Sold Till Month        6
Item Rejected           1       
Item Rejected Till Month    3
Year                2014
Month               April
Last Date of Month      04/30/2014
```

I have to find out Item_Sold, Item_Rejected, Item_Added for last three months where every next month it should be cumulative of all previous months values of Item_Sold, Item_Rejected, Item_Added

Comment: Your query does not make sense.  It uses table aliases such as `RSK` and `IA` that are not in the `from` clause.

Comment: What is the logic for the sold/rejected? All in all the query will be easier if rows and columns will be swapped, with one row per month, and the presentation layer left for a program or report

Comment: the query that you want to produce result for you
is not optimized version of primary query 
it`s different one

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2008, you can do this using a correlated subquery or using a non-equijoin.  SQL Server 2012 supports a cumulative sum function.  Here is a way to do it with a correlated subquery:

```
with ym as (
      SELECT COUNT(ITM.ID) AS ItemCount,
             Month(ITM.ItemProcureDate) as mon, Year(ITM.ItemProcureDate) as yr,
             Month(ITM.ItemProcureDate) + 100*Year(ITM.ItemProcureDate) as yyyymm
      FROM Rpt_Item ITM
      WHERE ITM.ItemProcureDate IS NOT NULL AND 
            ITM.ItemStatusID = 2 AND 
            ITM.ItemProcureDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME,'02/01/2014',1) AND 
            ITM.ItemProcureDate <= CONVERT(DATETIME,'04/12/2014',1)
      GROUP BY Month(ITM.ItemProcureDate), Year(ITM.ItemProcureDate) 
     )
select ym.*,
       (select sum(ItemCount)
        from ym ym2
        where ym.yyyymm <= ym.yyyy.mm
       ) as cumsum
from ym;
```

Note that this puts the year-month into a YYYYMM format.  This is just a convenience so the comparison on the time period uses only one column.

Also, if the `ITM` table is really big or is a view, then this might not perform as well as one would like.  If performance is an issue, use a temporary table instead of a CTE.  (SQL Server tends not to materialize CTEs so it is likely to run the code twice.)

Comment: Thanks Gordon, let me try your query.